# "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in K6" when trying to extract and add data from the month of March

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am making a project profits spreadsheet in Google sheets and when I extract the profits for given months usine Query, it returns the right values. However, when I have 2 dates for March and both have profits, I need them to be added together and displayed so the total profits for march are shows. Instead, I get an error and the #REF! symbol. Here is my spreadsheet, does anyone know what the problem is?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mTnPlR6inDUcvLWU2VPe-waSZgnPOJP4pN_JlBxRB2g/edit?usp=sharing

I first tried to add sum() to the query which is currently in the function for March, but it gave me the same error as it did without sum().

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard coding your criteria use cell reference `J3` to till last. Try-

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(TEXT($H$3:$H$18,"mmm")),$G$3:$G$18),
"select sum(Col2) where Col1='" & J3 & "' label sum(Col2) ''"),"")
```

To make it dynamic (no need to manually drag down the formula) spill array, use `BYROW()` or `MAP()` function.

```
=BYROW(J3:J14,LAMBDA(x,
IFERROR(QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(TEXT($H$3:$H$18,"mmm")),$G$3:$G$18),
"select sum(Col2) where Col1='" & x & "' label sum(Col2) ''"),"")))
```

To get result with sum at the bottom, use `VSTACK()` function.

```
=VSTACK(BYROW(J3:J14,LAMBDA(x,
IFERROR(QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(TEXT($H$3:$H$18,"mmm")),$G$3:$G$18),
"select sum(Col2) where Col1='" & x & "' label sum(Col2) ''"),""))),
SUM(G3:G18))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get all by a single formula, use-

```
=LET(mnts,INDEX(TEXT(DATE(2023,SEQUENCE(12),1),"mmm")),
VSTACK(HSTACK("Month","Profit"),
HSTACK(mnts,
BYROW(mnts,LAMBDA(x,
IFERROR(QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(TEXT($H$3:$H$18,"mmm")),$G$3:$G$18),
"select sum(Col2) where Col1='" & x & "' label sum(Col2) ''"),"")))),
HSTACK("Total",SUM(G3:G18))
))
```

[image]